# How to make a stretchable tableView header in swift 4?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, tableview, swift4

[image: First Image[![Second Image][1]]]

[image]

Hello, I have uploaded two images. Initially, my screen will look like First Image. If the user scrolls up the screen, then the screen will look like the Second Image. I have searched in GitHub and internet for a stretchable header. I found a solution where a view has made programmatically. But I am unable to load more two views inside that particular view for the design purpose. If I load a custom UI view it is showing error in this function ->

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
 let y = 300 - (scrollView.contentOffset.y + 300)
    let height = min(max(y, 60), 400)
    //imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: height)
    myNewView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: height)


}
```

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to GitHub libraries.
Here are some links to it.

1.A generic stretchy header for UITableView and UICollectionView

https://github.com/gskbyte/GSKStretchyHeaderView

2.A generic stretchy header for UIScrollView, and allows you to change navigation bar's appearance dynamically.

https://github.com/sunlubo/StretchyHeaderView

3.You can use one article which was found on medium.com

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/tutorial-creating-stretchy-layouts-on-ios-using-auto-layout-3fa974fa5e28

**Same thing I have done with CustomUIView by using this.**

https://github.com/maxep/MXSegmentedPager

Comment: Thanks for your reply madam I have viewed all those links. but unable to that. basically maximum example are with a imageView. I need a UIView. specially CustomUIView.